# Разделить входные данные, в <p:InputNumber

Tags: java, frontend, jsf

Мой ввод выглядит следующим образом 36,456.00 .
Нужен результат 36 456.00

```
<p:inputNumber value="#{payment.sum}" maxValue="100000000"
                                   lang="ru" decimalSeparator=" "
```

Установил атрибут decimalSeparator = "" - он дал результат 36456.00

Каким способом можно добавить пробел?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск по фразе "*primefaces inputNumber decimalSeparator space*" выдал мне [ссылку](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=46299) с таким вариантом решения:

```
<p:inputNumber id="numberfield" value="#{prospect.numberValue}" thousandSeparator="&nbsp;"/>
```

Т.е.:

1. Следует использовать `thousandSeparator`
2. Заменить пробел на `"&nbsp;"`

Comment: Спасибо, завтра попробую)

Comment: в моем случае помогло  `thousandSeparator="&#160;" `